# Siegel's theorem, best possible bound?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying classic Siegel's theorem, and I was wondering if that result is the best possible bound, meaning: is there a compact connected complex manifold $X$ of dimension $n$ in which $\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb{C}} K(X) = n$ ?

Also, is there one in which it is $0$? (I was thinking about the manifold made of a single point, but is there another less trivial one?) And more in general, how can I compute this value for the classic ones? (projective complex space, torus, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Any quasiprojective algebraic manifold (or indeed any quasiprojective algebraic variety at all) of dimension $n$ always has $\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbf C} K(X) = n$. (Indeed, this is a popular way to *define* the dimension of an algebraic variety!) This is very clear for projective space: picking an affine patch $\mathbf C^n$, the $n$ coordinate functions are an algebraically independent set which generate the field of meromorphic functions.
2. Yes, there are complex manifolds with no nonconstant meromorphic functions. The most common examples are complex tori $X=\mathbf C^n/\Lambda$: for a general choice of the lattice $\Lambda$, the only meromorphic functions on $X$ will be the constants.

A reference for these things is Chapter VIII of *Basic Algebraic Geometry* by Shafarevich.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll leave the question open for a while, are there any examples of a complex manifold of dimension $n$ in which it is neither 0 nor $n$ ?

Comment: Dear @AnalysisStudent0414, sure: for example, by taking a product $X \times Y$ of a complex torus with no meromorphic functions and an algebraic manifold $Y$, one can achieve any value between 0 and $n$.

Comment: Right. What about the other "classic" examples of complex varieties? If I can find that in the book you told me (sadly library's closed until 7th) just tell me, I can wait... otherwise, some referencies to do some research on my own?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so you'll probably do just as well googling as asking me. Anyway, there are K3 surfaces with no nonconstant meromorphic functions: see Verbitsky's answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167675/meromorphic-extension-of-local-defining-equations-of-a-complex-submanifold, also so-called Hopf surfaces, and so on. Another good reference is the book by Barth-Hulek-Peters-van de Ven. Soory I can't give more details.